# Polite way of asking questions

Tags: grammar, politeness

I think politeness is talking indirectly, softly or without being forceful or rude. So, I've mentioned some questions below which I think impolite way to ask. That's why, what are the polite way to ask them:

1. What is your name?
   (I ask when I meet or chat with someone unknown for the first time)
2. Who are you?
   (when I ask to an unknown person or when I received a call from unknown or when I received a friend request in fb from someone who I don't know exactly)
3. Where are you from?
   (when I ask someone where they live, or chatting or calling from)
4. What do you do (work)?
   (when I ask someone who I'm talking with first time and want to know what he does work)

Comment: Politeness in US speech is largely a matter of making it clear that you are not demanding responses but hoping that the other person will you do you the favor of responding. One polite way to ask questions is to open with "May I  ask ...?"; for instance, "May I ask your name?" "May I ask who I'm talking with?" "May I ask where you're from?"

Comment: @StoneyB's comment is excellent. I'd also add that sometimes all it takes is a simple greeting. Walking up to somebody at a party and saying 'What is your name?' would be very blunt. But, walking up and saying with a smile and a light tone of voice, 'Hello there, what's your name?' seems perfectly polite to me, assuming the social context is right. Once you've started your conversation, questions 3 & 4 would be totally fine and you wouldn't really need any additional fluff, especially with 4.

Comment: But. I'd appreciate the  Answer